# Issue poisson method rpart

Tags: predictive-models, cart, poisson-regression, rpart

I tried to use the rpart package to deal with observations count of crop pests, but I realized that there was overfitting with poisson method. In the vignette of the package, it said that it is possible to deal with it by modifying the shrink parameter, but which value do i need to put ? And maybe you know other packages that can deal with the poisson method with better prediction ?

Thanks guys